# A Heroic Riley Riddle Rises

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix, discovered ahead. 
>  My suffix had started instead. 
>  My infix may point with a role. 
>  I am cloaked by a joint super soul. 
>  
>  For example, a vampire flies one. 
>  He is bold, despite a lonely son. 
>  From a cave, he will free but requite. 
>  He is brave, wearing me like a knight. 
>  
>  It is told that a joke proves to kill, 
>  Unless saved by a stroke of good will; 
>  Though compare me to  that of a mask, 
>  And to wear me will combat the task.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

What is the answer to the Riley Riddle? 
 Who is *he*? 
 What is the task?

---

This will be my final Riley Riddle now because I want to get back at "normal" riddles. Yes, I say this a lot, but (I think) I mean it this time. The Riley rises.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the specifics but is He:

> BATMAN

And the task:

> Fighting Crime

Comment: The first part is true, the second is not. Hahah, that's what I wanted to make people think — and it worked! (ROT13) Gurer vf n ernfba jul V zragvbarq gur znfx... :D

Comment: @user477343 just a guess for the task is it rot13(gb fgbc onar orpnhfr bs gur znfx)?

Comment: No, not that... but there is a villain involved ;)

Answer (score 2):

**The riley riddle is**

> Robin

My prefix, discovered ahead.

> Most languages were developed in the past, **Ro** is an artificial international language that discards all previous words/roots and focused on ideas.

My suffix had started instead.

> **In** is the start of instead.

My infix may point with a role.

> **Obi** as in Obi-wan Kenobi, he appears through the Force, trying to guide Luke

I am cloaked by a joint super soul.

> He is apprenticed under Batman, so he's taken under Batman's wing. He is the one who outfits him. Batman is a super hero, part of the justice league --  a join effort.

**Who is he?**

> Batman

For example, a vampire flies one.

> A vampire is a Bat-Man

From a cave, he will free but requite.

> Batman's hideout is in a cave in spite of his fear of bats

He is brave, wearing me like a knight.

> Batman is Bruce Wayne's armor, and he protects the innocent even though he has no super powers

**What is the task?**

> Catching the joker

It is told that a joke proves to kill,

> Joker is a criminal

Unless saved by a stroke of good will;

> Normal police can't stop him, so Batman has to step in and save whomever he targets.

Though compare me to that of a mask,

> A joker, a persona you can put on

And to wear me will combat the task.

> Laughter staves off fear, so put on a joker persona and you'll be able to get through bad times/the issue at hand.

Comment: If I recall the answer correctly, yours is not it, I sadly inform. But oh, your answer can surely suffice, can it not? $(+1)$ ;) **Edit:** I might give you a tick, either from now to a couple of days, unless I can fully remember what the answer was... huh, would you look at that? I am riddled by my own riddle.