# A Heroic Riley Riddle (Risen)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

Before the [Hero](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72628/a-heroic-riley-riddle-risen) had risen, there was another before him.

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *My prefix rises when suspicious; 
>  See surprises, dark and raucous. 
>  
>  Our possession keeps my suffix; 
>  Hoots will freshen in the late ticks. 
>  
>  Gently down, my infix leads; 
>  Red around if awe proceeds. 
>  
>  Fly and flow, my affixes! 
>  I'm bes†owed on crucifixes.*
>
> ***What am I?***

What colour is the answer? 
 What is happening around it? 
 What are the three hidden words, including the answer?

---

This ends all. Big thanks to @[Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566/riley) for making these Riley Riddles. You deserve the answer, but a golden one instead :D

Comment: Lol, I guess you had to make one more Riley! :D

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I am a bit religious, so I had to dedicate a Riley to... hey, that will give it away! Hahah, that's all I'm saying for now :P

Comment: where is the infix part?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid sorry about that. 'Twas supposed to be the infix...

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I have answered my own riddle. I have not been active lately since I have earned the job of being a reporter for [*The Anagram Times*](https://www.anagramtimes.com/) and must submit at least three anagrams a day :)

Comment: awesome, will definitely check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> **Crown**. The colour is **brown**. And a **brawl** is happening around it.

`My prefix rises when suspicious;`

> Eyebrow $\to$ **brow**

`See surprises, dark and raucous.`

> **Crow**. Change the **b** to **c**. (c = *see* [surprises]).

`Our possession keeps my suffix;`

> Keeping via a possession $\to$ **Own**. Overall, this makes **crown** or **brown**.

`Hoots will freshen in the late ticks.`

> **Owl**. Change **n** to **l**. "Freshen = Fresh *n*" and owls are awake at night, in the *late ticks* (time).

`Gently down, my infix leads;`

> **Row**. (Row, row, row your boat. *Gently down* the stream...). Also in *c****row****n* and *b****row****n*.

`Red around if awe proceeds.`

> **Raw**. "*Red* raw" and it has *aw* in it. From this you can make **brawl**, but do not make the word *crawl* because it starts with *c* (pro**cee**ds) and *red around* could refer to a STOP sign (red and roundish). So *stop with crawl*.

`Fly and flow, my affixes!`

> **Crows** and **owls** fly. You can **row** a boat (flowing).

`I'm bes†owed on crucifixes.`

> The **brown crown** worn by Jesus. When he was crucified, there was a **brawl** surrounding him. This answers the three questions.

---

**Title:**

`A Heroic Riddle (Risen)`

> Jesus Christ was said to be **risen** three days after he was crucified.

Also,

> @Riley deserves a **golden** crown :D

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton thanks! I'm surprised I still remember the answer, hahah :P

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer as correct ;P

Comment: @Sensoray hmm... I was just being modest, really ;)

Comment: it's so'kay to. Otherwise people will keep looking at it in the unsolved category and then they'll be disappointed when they click into it and it's been solved but not checked.  I'm glad you posted an answer though. Wish I had been on and seen it when it was posted ^-^

Comment: @Sensoray Oh, really? I did not know that. Eh, I suppose that justifies why I should accept the answer. Thanks for letting me know of that! I appreciate it. Hopefully I'll make more riddles to come that you can maybe take a crack at :P

Comment: I just noticed your other one, I'mma take a crack at it :]

Comment: @Sensoray It's already been solved if you wanna take a look at the answer. But thanks for willing to check it out! I might as well check out some of your stuff, too.... wait, that sounds wrong... you know what I mean xD

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

Part A:

> Our possession keeps my suffix; Hoots will freshen in the late ticks. --> Our possession=heart, suffix= Holy Spirit?

Part B:

> Fly and flow, my affixes!  I'm bes†owed on crucifixes. --> Jesus Christ? the cross instead of the 't' and "crucifixes"?

Part C:

> Gently down, my prefix leads;Red around if awe proceeds --> Jesus Christ? Red = blood, Gently down --> implying Jesus bearing the cross to Calvary?

Part D:

> Three hidden words= trinity, i.e. Father, Son, Spirit?

Part E:

> Colour = White, representing Holy? (a wild guess)

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant "infix" in the third line, not my prefix. $(+1)$ for your effort. I will personally answer this one.

Comment: No problemo! Glad that someone else took a crack at this riddle :D